# Extensão ".js" perde o caminho relativo em módulos do RequireJS

Tags: javascript, módulo-ecmascript, requirejs

Estou usando Bable ou Typescript para transpilar meus módulos ES6 para AMD. O problema é que se o arquivo tem extensão o RequireJS não consegue ao localizar os arquivos, procura na raíz do projeto ao invés de ser relativo ao arquivo.

---

**Assim não funciona em módulo ES6:**

src/index.js

```
import { counter } from './conter.js';
```

dist/index.js

```
define(["./counter.js"], function (_counter) {});
```

---

**Assim funciona em módulo AMD:**

src/index.js

```
import { counter } from './conter';
```

dist/index.js

```
define(["./counter"], function (_counter) {});
```

---

Estou precisando de uma solução que funcione em ambos.